# Unable to save file from FileProvider

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I am capturing images from android application and saving images in external storage using `Fileprovider`. But it is giving me an exception as follow

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.rocketstove/files/SAMS/JMC-R-1256655/application_form_first.jpg
```

I have configured provider in androidManifest like this

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

I have also add following line in file_paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

In java code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        File imagePath = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "SAMS");
        if (!imagePath.exists()) {
            imagePath.mkdir();
        }
        imagePath = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/SAMS", rocketId);
        if (!imagePath.exists()) {
            imagePath.mkdir();
        }
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath.getPath(), filename);
        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        String authority = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), authority, imageFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Edit**
file_paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="Android/data/com.rocketstove.files/"/>
</paths>
```

Java code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        File file
                 =getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File imagePath = new File(file , rocketId);
        if (!imagePath.exists()) {
            imagePath.mkdir();
        }
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath.getPath(), filename);
        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        String authority = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), authority, imageFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Error

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rocketstove/files/JMC-R-4555555/application_form_first.jpg
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:719)
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:404)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have also add following line in file_paths

You have `external-path`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles) states that this:

> Represents files in the root of the external storage area. The root path of this subdirectory is the same as the value returned by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

That is not where your `File` points to.

Change `external-path` to `files-path`, since your Java code uses `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: But i need to store on external storage.

Comment: @BibekShakya: Then do not use `getFilesDir()`. Ideally, use `getExternalFilesDir()`, and then change `external-path` to `external-files-path`.

Comment: @BibekShakya: It should be a complaining about a different file path. Otherwise, you did not change your Java code.

Comment: it is using java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android file path which is internal storage

Comment: You then can use both external-path and external-files-path. As the function name tells you getExternalFilesDir() delivers external storage.

Comment: @BibekShakya: Replace `path="Android/data/com.rocketstove.files/"` with `path="."`.

Comment: @BibekShakya: I don't know what to tell you. `<external-files-path name="name" path="." />` will match files inside of `getExternalFilesDir()`. You need to look through your code and XML to determine where the disconnect is.

Comment: it is still writing to internal storage but not sd card

Comment: @BibekShakya: It is writing to what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). External storage is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), such as an SD card. Neither of those are what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).